# Django rest framework: Mixed content

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mixed-content

I am quite new in Django rest framework. I have a project which contain Django restframework API inside a Django site project(with simple frontend code) and it works fine in my local environment. However in the production domain(HTTPS) it shows as below:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<my production domain>/audience/labeling_jobs/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<my production domain>/audience/labeling_jobs/api/jobs/?page=2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have setup the configuration about SSL/HTTPS according to Django document [SSL/HTTPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/security/#ssl-https) beforehand but it still got this error.

```
 USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
 SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
 SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
 CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

 SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
 SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
 SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
 SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

It seems that the Django rest cannot get the correct HTTPS, but it works fine with other django paths, they can be showed on the production page.

Is there anything I have missed?

EDIT:
Below is the code which request the django rest api:
the function is trying to shows the django labeling_jobs data via restframework API, and paging.

```
{% block custom_script %}
    <script type="module">
        const Jobs = {
            data() {
                return {
                    job_api_url: '{% url "labeling_jobs:api-job-detail" %}',
                    data: '',
                    next_page_url: null,
                    previous_page_url: null,
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.getJobs()
            },
            computed: {
                jobs() {
                    return this.data.results
                }
            },
            methods: {
                async getJobs(url) {
                    url = url ? url : this.job_api_url
                    const response = await axios.get(url)
                    this.data = await response.data
                    this.next_page_url = this.data.next
                    this.previous_page_url = this.data.previous
                },
                next_page() {
                    console.log(this.next_page_url)
                    if (this.next_page_url) {
                        this.getJobs(this.next_page_url)
                    }
                },
                previous_page() {
                    console.log(this.previous_page_url)
                    if (this.previous_page_url) {
                        this.getJobs(this.previous_page_url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const app = Vue.createApp(Jobs)
        app.config.compilerOptions.delimiters = ['[[', ']]']
        app.mount('#wrapper')
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT 2
I found the problem is something related to the paging django restframework, when I place the API url on the browser with production host view them under django rest ui, it is OK, but it fails when I try to move to next page.

Comment: Looks like your JS is trying to load something over HTTP, can you share the JS that requests the `/audience/labeling_jobs/api/jobs/` API?

Comment: I think you are making a http request from your js end. Try making a https request

Comment: @IainShelvington Sure, I have updated the js code.

Comment: @WeberHuang do you have a webserver, like nginx, proxying the requests to Django? Can you share this config as you may need to modify it to pass the correct headers

Comment: @IainShelvington I haven't start Nginx since the former project owner built all of them in the same sever (I think i should start).

Comment: How is the project running/accessed in production? There must be some kind of webserver or LB handling SSL?

Comment: @IainShelvington This project is run on one of the sever (172.190...) in our team and deployed to the specific domain https.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem,
by adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` in the head of `base.html` and adding the following config in the `settings.py` :

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('X-FORWARDED-PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

And it can show the contents by sending the correct HTTPS url without redirect to the wrong HTTP domain name.

But I still think it is not a best answer, I will dive into django restframework pagination maybe with relative url to try to get something more robust.